# Setup SQL Server JDBC Connection Pool and Resource on Tomcat 7

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat7, connection-pooling

Firstly let me start off by saying I've been Googling for quite some time now and I can't find a straight forward answer to this. Either my Google-Fu is terrible or there really isn't a clear and simple way of doing this. Even on the official site I get pages and pages of jargon.

I'm used to Glassfish and am quite spoiled when it comes to connection pool setup especially with the Glassfish admin console. What I'm looking for is just a simple step by step, e.g. 'Go to this file, add this xml tag', paste your JDBC driver in that folder, done'. But I can't find something like that.

What I have is

- The Server IP Address the Database is on
- The database name
- The username
- Password
- and JDBC Driver .jar file

It would greatly be appreciated if someone can clear things up for me a bit. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear why Glassfish and Tomcat7

Comment: Tomcat, not Glassfish

Answer (score 0):

Here is the document for setup tomcat connection pool using [DBCP](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/DBCP)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking on how to setup a connection pool on Tomcat. Not Glassfish...